# SELECT DISTINCT doesn't appear to work with big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am filtering to a second created table that have duplicates removed. However I'm finding that DISTINCT seems not be working, and I end up with rows with identical `ids`. I want to only select one unique `ID` and throw any remaining ones away, but this is not what is happening. In other-words I do not care about the other column names.

```
def de_dupe_affiliates(read_table, write_table):
    query = """
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `{write_table}` AS
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, BRAND, TITLE, SHORT_TITLE, PRICE, FROM `{read_table}` 
    """.format(read_table=read_table,write_table=write_table)
    response = client.query(query).result()
```

I also tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ID), BRAND
```

But this did the same. Is it possible to do this with a DISTINCT on one column?

Comment: Distinct applies to every column in your select. Try using `qualify row_number() over (partition by id order by <whatever columns you want> = 1`.

Comment: every column counts for the distinct, maybe a GROUP BY will be better

Comment: @Andrew Does that syntax work for BQ (BigQuery)

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. I.e. `SELECT DISTINCT(ID), BRAND` is the same as `SELECT DISTINCT ID, BRAND`, and also the same as `SELECT DISTINCT ID, (BRAND)`.

Comment: @disruptive - according to the internets it does - [clicky](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause)

Comment: here is more information https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t) FROM (
  SELECT ID, BRAND, TITLE, SHORT_TITLE, PRICE FROM read_table
) t 
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Your select clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, BRAND, TITLE, SHORT_TITLE, PRICE FROM `{read_table}`
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT ID, BRAND, TITLE, SHORT_TITLE, PRICE FROM `{read_table}` GROUP BY ID, BRAND, TITLE, SHORT_TITLE, PRICE
```

meaning any differences **within these fields** creates new rows in your result.

Your query works only if ID, BRAND, TITLE, SHORT_TITLE, PRICE fields are unique.

If not, you may use window functions like `row_number()` or `rank()` to select one row per id.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example of the row_number() logic in BQ?